How do I get selenium to consistently find and use an element when creating a Kahoot quiz?
I'm creating a auto type answer Kahoot quiz from a spreadsheet using selenium. Here is an excerpt of some of my code below, and a excerpt to some of the df I'm using. Everything else should work, however on lines 87 to 91 it can't consistently create a new type answer question and on lines 98 to 101 it can't consistently type out the questions and answers. When something goes wrong with either it's because the web element couldn't be found, which confuses me because the code works properly sometimes.
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import openpyxl

# put in spreadsheet
df = pd.read_excel('1000 of the most common Spanish Nouns.xlsx')

# Type in your email or username
email = 'email'
password = 'password'

folder_name = input('Folder Name: ')
quiz_question_length = int(input('Length of each quiz: '))

# set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# go to kahoot login
driver.get('https://create.kahoot.it/auth/login')

# type kahoot account credentials
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username').send_keys(f"{email}")
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys(f"{password}")

# get rid of potential popup
try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[id="onetrust-pc-btn-handler"]').click()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="ot-pc-refuse-all-handler"]').click()
    print('skipped cookie popup')
except:
    print('no cookie popup')

# press login
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[id="login-submit-btn"]').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_contains("create.kahoot.it"))

# skip second popup
try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Next"]').click()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Next"]').click()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class="btn btn--text"]').click()
    print('skipped second popup')
except:
    print('no second popup')

# go to kahoot account's library
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-functional-selector="side-bar-link__library"]').click()

# create a new folder for kahoot quiz
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-functional-selector="library_side-bar_create-folder"]').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[placeholder="New folder"]').send_keys(f'{folder_name}', Keys.ENTER)

# split df into multiple different parts
quizzes = []
for i in range(0, len(df), quiz_question_length):
    if i + quiz_question_length < len(df) + 1:
        quizzes.append(df.iloc[i:i + quiz_question_length])
    else:
        quizzes.append(df.iloc[i:])

# begin creating quizzes
for quiz in quizzes:
    # create new kahoot quiz
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        'button[class="button__Button-sc-c6mvr2-0 iwRYhY create-button__PrimaryButton-sc-1wmq7f8-0 jaZrfx"]').click()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Create new Kahoot."]').click()

    # choose blank option for kahoot quiz
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="styles__FlowOptionInnerContainer-sc-hcxgxq-2 gmFgAG"]').click()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="flat-button__FlatButton-sc-6uljam-0 iEWtrJ"]').click()

    # close the theme panel
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Close Themes panel"]').click()

    # PROBLEM WITH ADDING A NEW TYPE ANSWER QUESTION
    for index, row in quiz.iterrows():
        # add new answer type question
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        add_question_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-functional-selector="add-question-button"]')
        add_question_btn.click()
        answer_type_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-functional-selector="create-button__open-ended"]')
        answer_type_btn.click()

        # set up question and answer input from spreadsheet
        question_input = row['Question']
        answer_input = row['Answer']

        # PROBLEM WITH ADDING QUESTION AND ANSWER TEXT TO QUESTION
        question_text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[data-placeholder="Start typing your question"]')
        question_text.send_keys(question_input)
        answer_text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[placeholder="Type an answer"]')
        answer_text.send_keys(answer_input)
```

df = {
    'Question': ['la explosión', 'el apellido', 'la conferencia', 'la intensidad', 'el paquete'],
    'Answer': ['explosion', 'last name', 'conference', 'intensity', 'package']
}

I think what I need to do is have the webdriver wait until it finds the elements it needs clickable or able to be typed, because the elements are definitely there. I've heard of using explicit waits for that however I'm unsure how to go about it. I'm a new coder so this may be a little messy and was just a little project I wanted to work on.

for your own sake remove your login credentials from your code!  And can you be more specific about the error you're getting? which specific line(s) raise an exception, and is it NoSuchElementException or something else?

sorry I forgot to remove the first thing mentioned and for the second thing the error is this, "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame". This occurs precisely on lines 89, 91, 99, and 101. This is where it is either clicking a button or typing out a question or answer.

This is where it is either clicking a button or typing out a question or answer, however I believe that the error may lead into how I handled the lines mentioned above, but that's where I'm getting it.

So I managed to solve the issue myself. I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but essentially I just have the program excecute a while loop until the code mentioned above works here it is:
    for index, row in quiz.iterrows():
    # add new answer type question
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    while True:
        try:
            add_question_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-functional-selector="add-question-button"]')))
            add_question_btn.click()
            break
        except:
            pass
    while True:
        try:
            answer_type_btn = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-functional-selector="create-button__open-ended"]')))
            answer_type_btn.click()
            break
        except:
            pass

    # set up question and answer input from spreadsheet
    question_input = row['Question']
    answer_input = row['Answer']

    # add questions and answer text to newly created question
    while True:
        try:
            question_text = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[data-placeholder="Start typing your question"]')))
            question_text.send_keys(question_input)
            break
        except:
            pass
    while True:
        try:
            answer_text = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[placeholder="Type an answer"]')))
            answer_text.send_keys(answer_input)
            break
        except:
            pass

